# How to get the name of class and method?

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

I have a PHP code like this:

```
class class_name
{
    public function function_name()
    {
        /**  I need to "class_name" and "function_name" in here
          *  How can I get them?
          */
    }
}
```

As you see in the code's comment, I need to `class_name` and `function_name`. How can I get them? I think `get_class($this);` will be fine for getting the name of class. But actually my main question is about getting the name of method ...

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: `__CLASS__` and `__METHOD__`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks. `__CLASS__` is fine. But `__METHOD__` returns both class name and method name. Something like this: `class_name::function_name`. Is it possible to I get just `function_name` ?

Comment: Well `function_name` is the part that comes after the `::` so a few options spring to mind: `$method = explode('::', __METHOD__)[1]` or `list(, $method) = explode('::', __METHOD__)`

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments:

```
class class_name
{
    public function function_name()
    {
        echo __CLASS__;     // output: class_name
        echo __FUNCTION__;  // output: function_name
    }
}
```

But the way, for getting both of them, You have to use `__METHOD__` which returns `class_name::function_name`.